# Newly installed Windows 10 not working as it should

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I have just installed Windows 10. Everything was running fine: I removed all the pinned programs from Start menu and installed some programs. Then I tried to pin them in the Start. So here is the problem: they stay pinned for a 2-3 seconds then the pinning is getting reverted by itself. Even if I try to change any of the settings related to Start menu they revert on their own. Tried to search in Google but I couldn't find the exact problem there...

Comment: Add some screen shots of before and after both if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a Start menu issue, run start menu troubleshooter at first. Download it from Microsoft website.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12385/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-opening-start-menu-cortana

Besides, you could check the pinned shortcuts in the path:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned

Finally, create a new account to test again.

Comment: Everything is running fine after the troubleshooter. :)